# Avoid spaces and count the characters (using sum() function)

Tags: python, string, sum

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate working of 
# Avoid Spaces in Characters Frequency
# Using isspace() + sum()
  
# initializing string
test_str = 'geeksforgeeks 33 is   best'
  
# printing original string
print("The original string is : " + str(test_str))
  
# isspace() checks for space 
# sum checks count 
res = sum(not chr.isspace() for chr in test_str)
      
# printing result 
print("The Characters Frequency avoiding spaces : " + str(res))
```

I found this code in geeksforgeeks and i cant understand it , In the line where the sum() is used , they are using list comprehension right so we have to use the brackets([ ]) but they havent used it , and the line [not chr.isspace() for chr in test_str] returns a list of true and false but how come the output of the gives the correct value of the length of string without the spaces

Comment: You don’t need to put `str(…)` around a string, it’s useless.

Comment: This is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), not a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are a few tricks to that line.

First, in python, type

```py
>>>True == 1
True
>>>False == 0
True
>>> True + True 
2
>>> True + False
1
```

This is why the sum works: the booleans are interpreted as integers. The sum therefore is the number of values that are `True` in the generator.

Second, the list comprehension without square braces is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)